# Make css columns always float left

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to create a grid with columns. The problem is that once a column is bigger than the other, the next column won't float to the left anymore. Is there anyway I can fix this?

[image: The floating problem]

The code for the column is simple:

```
.column { width: 320px; float: left; }
```

I want to avoid defining a height or use a float: right.

Thank you

Comment: Sadly, there's no quick, vastly compatible css only solution. You will need to create three columns and place those items inside those columns or use javascript

Comment: @JonasGrumann I cannot agree with you on that, see my answer below.

Comment: @sdcr You can see from your fiddle that the cleared columns are not equidistant from the box immediately above them. If OP is looking for a masonry-like layout, [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) is the way to go (yes, JS is needed).

Comment: @JonasGrumann agreed, but based on OP's question, I guess my answer would work for the problem like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding clear fix by using `nth-child` could be a solution.

```
.column:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both; /* on row 4,7,10,13,16... */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0nxb6xnL/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. When I run this code, all column will float vertically underneath each other instead of horizontally next to each other.

Comment: Keep your float like before `.column { width: 320px; float: left; }`

Comment: It's still like that.

Comment: it's hard to say where the problem is, check out the the demo above see if it helps, or share a link if you have a live site.

Comment: Ah, it works now. (made a stupid code mistake before). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is happening for different height. Can you make the height identical and try again?

Like

```
.column { width: 320px; height: 200px; float: left; }
```

Comment: That's the point, I do not want to define a height for the columns.

Comment: In that case may be you need to change the layout or use javascript to place the column in absolute position. May be a better solution to use both three column layout and javascript. You can have 3 div for three column which are float left. Then use javascript to put ".column" elements to their respective column div. Even then it is little bit tricky if you do not want one column div get much higher than other, you may require calculation.